# How to use ARGS in bash builtin getopts

Tags: bash

I am trying to use bash builtin `getopts` to parse input parameters.

```
getopts OPTSTRING VARNAME [ARGS...]
```

I can see a lot of examples of how to use `OPTSTRING` and `VARNAME` but I haven't been able to find single working example of how ARGS can be used.

Does anyone use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help getopts`:

> Getopts normally parses the positional parameters ($0 - $9), but if more arguments are given, they are parsed instead.

One way to use `ARGS` would be if you had a variable containing arguments to process *instead* of the script's (or function's) arguments.  I tested this from the shell prompt:

```
$ args="-xzf foo.tgz"
$ while getopts tcvxzjf: opt $args; do echo $? - $opt - $OPTARG; done
0 - x -
0 - z -
0 - f - foo.tgz
$
```

Comment: oh, thanks for the example.

I misunderstood the purpose of `ARGS`, I thought this is where I can define options without switch parameters.